# How to pass arguments into a function as formula arguments like y ~ x

Tags: r, function, evaluation, expression-evaluation

I am trying to write a function that calls another function that requires formula arguments. However, I'm not able to pass the y ~ x arguments to the inner function.

Without the wrapping function it works:

```
test.df <- data.frame("test.x" = c(1,1,1,2,2), "test.y" = 1:5)
my.result <-lm(data = test.df, formula = test.y ~ test.x)
```

But I want this to work:

```
example.function <- function(my.data, my.y){
  my.result <- lm(data = my.data, formula = my.y ~ test.x) 
  return(my.result)
}

example.function(my.data = test.df, my.y = test.y) 
# Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'test.y' not found

example.function(my.data = test.df, my.y = "test.y") 
# Error in model.frame.default(formula = my.y ~ test.x, data = my.data, :
# variable lengths differ (found for 'test.x')
```

I tried to use `{{}}` but this also doesn't work:

```
example.function <- function(my.data, my.y){
  my.result <- lm(data = my.data, formula = {{my.y}} ~ test.x) 
  return(my.result)
}

example.function(my.data = test.df, my.y = test.y)
# Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'test.y' not found

example.function(my.data = test.df, my.y = "test.y")
# Error in model.frame.default(formula = { :
# variable lengths differ (found for 'test.x')
```

And I also tried to use `enquo()` and `!!` but this doesn't work either:

```
example.function <- function(my.data, my.y){
  enquo(my.y)
  my.result <- lm(data = my.data, formula = !! my.y ~ test.x) 
  return(my.result)
}

example.function(my.data = test.df, my.y = test.y)
# Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'test.y' not found

example.function(my.data = test.df, my.y = "test.y")
# Error in !my.y : invalid argument type
```

Thank you for any help understanding this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gives what was asked for.

On the other hand you might consider not using non-standard evaluation (NSE) and instead pass a character string for `my.y` since then it becomes easy to pass a variable holding the variable name and not just hard coding the call.  Also the code becomes shorter.  We show that as `example.function2` at the end.

```
example.function <- function(my.data, my.y) {
  my.y <- deparse(substitute(my.y))
  fo <- reformulate("test.x", my.y)
  do.call("lm", list(fo, substitute (my.data)))
}

example.function(my.data = test.df, my.y = test.y)
```

giving

```
Call:
lm(formula = test.y ~ test.x, data = test.df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       test.x  
       -0.5          2.5
```

Same but without NSE.  Output is the same.

```
example.function2 <- function(my.data, my.y) {
  fo <- reformulate("test.x", my.y)
  do.call("lm", list(fo, substitute (my.data)))
}

example.function2(my.data = test.df, my.y = "test.y")
```

Comment: I was trying to do the NSE because later I pass the same arguments into a ggplot call. Thanks for explaining both ways! I have one question about the NSE way- why use `do.call` and `substitute(my.data)`? It also works for me as `my.result <- lm(data = my.data, formula = fo)`

Comment: The Call: line in the output won't come out right if you don't do that.  In ggplot2 you can do this to avoid NSE: `ggplot(test.df, aes(.data[["test.x"]], .data[["test.y"]])) + geom_point()`